# Rename files with specific extension and append date in unix

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

I want to rename below files as follows.

```
Original files : 
x.1.gz
y.1.gz
```

Rename it to

```
x.dateTime.gz
y.dateTime.gz
```

I am using following script to do the same. But **it is deleting files instead of renaming.**

```
for file in *.1.gz; do
    mv "$file" "$($(date +’%Y%m%d%H%M’) "$file" .1.gz).gz"
done
```

Comment: How about this : rename 1 `date +%Y%m%d%H%M` *.gz

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
for i in *.1.gz; do mv "$i" "$(basename $i .1.gz).$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M').gz"; done
```

`basename` will extract the first part of the filename.

Note that the `date` command is using single quote `'` and not the one you put on your question.

Comment: You can skip `basename` altogether with `${i%.1.gz}`.

Comment: This works in command line. But when I am using in script, It is giving me error as : mv can not stat file, because we are using *. any solution for that ?

Comment: @KrunalParmar The error you get is unlikely to happen because if the file would not be there (can not stat file), globbing would not occur and the `for` loop would not execute, and so `mv` would also not start. If you have this error, there must be something fishy with your file or directory structure.

Comment: @oliv File is there. I am able to run the same line from command prompt. What I think is, It is taking *.1.gz as a file name and not taking * as a wildcard while using via script.

Comment: @KrunalParmar If you put this line in a script and you don't run this one from the folder where are located the files, then change the `for` loop by adding the path to your folder, e.g `/path/to/my/folder/*.1.gz`